# Active voice in mathematical physics derivation

Tags: tenses, science, active-voice

Im currently writing an undergraduate physics report, collaborating with a large group of people. One of our sections requires some LONG lagrangian derivations for various systems. Now, everyone always seems to insist on using the passive voice for physics reports, but in my opinion, in a long derivation it is incredibly clumsy. I'd like some  professional opinion on this matter, thank you.

example sentence:

active:
"we now write the lagrangian in terms of the generalised coordinates alpha and phi"

passive:
"the lagrangian was written in terms of the generalised coordinates...."

Comment: If you are asking which of the two sentences is better, I am afraid you are asking for an opinion that can't be easily supported by reference, Why not ask your professor or look up the existing research paper, academic journal or something?

Comment: @Rathony I suspect a lot of people will find Peter's solution better than either. It avoids the clumsy lengthy passive **and** the naff 'we'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No doubt about it.

Comment: "*Here is the lagrangian in terms of the generalized coordinates:*" Or if there is a whole section that presents this then just entitle the section: "*The Lagrangian In Terms of the Generalized Coordinates*".

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> Rewriting the Lagrangian in terms of the generalized coordinates α and ϕ yields ...

It's active voice, but doesn't use "we", which I think is the underlying reason for using the passive voice in scientific papers.

Comment: This is so sensible I'm not even going to look for the previous passive vs active debates (I'm fairly sure this solution wasn't suggested there).

Comment: Isn't this what my grammar teacher condemned as a "dangling participle"?

Answer (score 1):

Try "Here is the Lagrangian in terms of the generalised coordinates...." (The fact that it is *written* can be inferred.)  Or, in the form of a title: "The Lagrangian in terms of the generalised coordinates....:"

It would be good if you could include an indication of why the Lagrangian is being recast in this way.  These little chunks of text in the derivation ought to explain the purpose of each step, as a guide to readers.  Where are you headed?